# DataContract & DataMember attributes - how they affect type

Tags: wcf, datacontract

what is the difference between class without DataContract attributes:

```
public class BankOperationResult
{        
    public int CurrentAmount { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
}
```

and the same class with DataContract attributes:

```
[DataContract]
public class BankOperationResult
{        
    [DataMember]
    public int CurrentAmount { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool Success { get; set; }
}
```

I mean, does WCF treats those two types in different way when encoding etc.?

With or without those attributes my WCF service works...

Thanks, Pawel

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Before .NET 3.5 SP1 if you didn't mark your property with a DataMember attribute it was not exposed in the WSDL and not serialized. Starting from .NET 3.5 SP1 the [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) will automatically include all public properties, so you no longer need to decorate them with this attribute.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not *quite* that simple in the 3.5 SP1 case, but that's the basic idea. Without any DataContract or DataMember attributes defined on your class, all fields *and* properties will be serialized into XML and this includes the private auto-generated backing store fields for automatic properties of the form `public int MyValue { get; set; }` and will name them `<MyValue>k__BackingField`. Adding the DataContract and DataMember attributes explicitly will have the DataContractSerializer forego the private field serialization.